# Passing a prepared statement to a DECLARE CURSOR in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I prepare sql query how can I pass this query to `DECLARE _cname CURSOR FOR _query`?

Can I simply replace _query to my prepared statement in MySql??
Is that happen without calling `EXECUTE stmts USING @v;`

Please help me to pass prepared statement TO DECLARE _C CURSOR SQL_STMT !!!
Is that possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not yet any answer here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,116597,116597

Comment: did it, using temporary tables :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you explain how you did it? Thanks!